# Proof of existence of solution to first-order ODE over given interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a differential equation of the form $\dot{x} = f(t, x)$, where $f: J \times W \to E$, with $J$ some open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $W$ an open subset of a normed vector space $E$, I'm looking for a proof that if $f$ is $C^1$ (continuously differentiable) with respect to $x$, the existence of a solution $x: I \to W$ to the differential equation with initial condition $x(t_0) = x_0$ defined over some interval $I$ containing $t_0$ implies that there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that for any $y_0 \in U$, there exists a solution to the differential equation $y: I \to W$ with the initial condition $y(t_0) = y_0$.

The key implication I'm looking for is that the solution $y$ is defined over the *same* interval as $x$ by virtue of starting "close enough" to the starting point of $x$.

Comment: In the case of $E = \mathbb{R}^n$, this follows from the fact that the estimates used to invoke the contraction mapping theorem imply that for any compact $K \subset W$, there is a uniform time of existence for initial data in $K$, I.e. there is $T > 0$ such that for any $x_0$ in $K$, the solution exists on $[-T, T]$. See page 80 of http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look at the linked PDF file. But it seems like your comment addresses the question of existence of some $T > 0$ such that the solution exists on $[-T, T]$, whereas my question takes as given some interval $I = [a, b]$ over which a solution is known to exist, and is about whether it can be proven that a solution over the same interval exists, provided the initial conditions are "close enough".

Comment: Yes you are right. But it is known that the set $\{ (t ,x_0) : \text{ The integral curve starting at $x_0$ is defined at time $t$} \}$ is open. See Lee's introduction to smooth manifolds for proof. If $I$ is compact, then I think what you want is true.

Comment: Thanks very much! It's taken a while to work through Lee's proof but I'm now happy with this result. I am indeed interested only in the case where $I$ is compact.